# Passing HashMap to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to display a list of elements using this JSP code:

```
                 <c:forEach items="${themesContentMap}" var="entry">
                    <tr>
                    <td><input  type="checkbox" value="${entry.key.getId()}"checked></td>
                    <td>${entry.key.getLibelle()}</td>
                    <td>${entry.value.getNom()}</td>
                    </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
```

Fed by the java code:

```
    HashMap<ThemeBean, CoursBean> themeContentMap = new HashMap<ThemeBean, CoursBean>();
    for (ThemeBean theme : themeBeans) {
        themeContentMap.put(theme, coursDAO.getCours(theme.getCours()));
    }
    LOG.debug("Found matching: " + themeContentMap);
    request.setAttribute("themesContentMap", themeContentMap);
    resp.sendRedirect(LIST_THEMES);
```

However I don't get anything in my webpage, nor any error in the logs (the debug is displaying correct informations).

Please note that I'm a complete beginner with servlets and JSP, so I might be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  resp.sendRedirect(LIST_THEMES);
```

creates a new request and hence, previous request attributes are lost.
You have to use a `RequestDispatcher` here.

```
RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("yourJspName");
view.forward(request, response);
```

By this way, you will be able to access your request attributes in jsp.
You need to understand the [difference between a request dispatcher and redirect](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/12/16/request-getrequestdispatcher-response-sendredirect/)

This is how a **request dispatcher** works:
[image]

This is how a **response.sendRedirect()** works
[image]

[This tutorial will help](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/12/16/request-getrequestdispatcher-response-sendredirect/)

Comment: Also is `"${entry.key.getId()}"` valid EL? If I remember correctly (and my knowledge may be little outdated) `getID()` is not valid in JSPs EL. Simple `.id` should be fine.

Comment: @Pshemo, yes, you should access based on properties.

Answer (score 3):

`sendRedirect()` sends the header back to the browser (302 HTTP status code),
And Also contains the name of the resource to be redirected to. So this will be a new request to the resource from the browser.
You have to  Forward the request

```
requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

Jsp takes the request and there attributes and further process it.